# Android sending images to server

Tags: php, android, bitmap, server, base64

I am trying to send images taken from my phone to a server, with the code below the app crashes when I try to upload a picture taken from my phone, I know the code works because I am able to upload images I have downloaded onto my phone.

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        String fileNameSegments[] = picturePath.split("/");
        fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];

        Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
        myImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        // Encode Image to String
        encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);

    }
}
```

the code that uploads

```
   public void uploadImage() {

    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://serverwebsite.com/image.php";
    Log.d("URL", url);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                Log.e("RESPONSE", response);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "The image is upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("JSON Exception", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Error while loadin data!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Error [" + error + "]");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Cannot connect to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("image", encodedString);
            params.put("filename", fileName);

            return params;

        }

    };
    rq.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code help you

```
public void sendImage(MediaType mediaType)
{
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
            .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
            .addPart(
                    Headers.of("Content-Disposition",
                            "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=" + '"'
                                    + name + '"'),
                    RequestBody.create(mediaType, new File(getFileAdress()
                    ))).build();
    final String credential = Credentials.basic(userName, pass);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .header("Authorization", credential)
            .url(WebServiceAddress())
            .post(requestBody).build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        int code=response.code();
        String out = response.body().string();

        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

        } else {

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

}
```

This is my library addresses that I use for resizing photos :
https://github.com/alireza-87/ImageHelper